# How to debug error that's caused by Outlook when closing due to VSTO Add-In?

Tags: outlook, .net-4.0, vsto

I have developed a VSTO Add-In for Outlook which seems to be working normally. However, when I close Outlook client I get the following error message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: OUTLOOK.EXE
  Problem Signature 02: 12.0.6776.5000
  Problem Signature 03: 59a44e6f
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.7.2116.0
  Problem Signature 06: 59c475d2
  Problem Signature 07: 3af5
  Problem Signature 08: e
  Problem Signature 09: System.Exception
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.27
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
  Brand:    Office12Crash
  skulcid:  1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

with the following screen shot:

[image]

This mainly happens when I first install the add-in. In between, sometimes when closing Outlook no such error happens. Does anyone have an idea how to go about debugging this error? All my research just points to disabling the add-in...

The Outlook version is 2007. VSTO add-in target environment is .NET 4.0.

Comment: Are you using any multi-threading? I've seen similar things happen in Word under that circumstance.

Comment: Yeah, it's multi-threaded. I think it's caused by  background thread I was running.